# GAE java migrating from Java 8 to 11 - Deployment issues and local dev server issues

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-gae-plugin

I had a Java 8 app on GAE standard runtime that was working fine. Apparently, Java 8 deployments are no longer supported after Jan 31 2024. I am trying to migrate to Java 11 and deploy. I was using Eclipse with Google Plugin earlier to run locally and right click and Deploy to App Engine standard and it was seamless.

This is what I did so far

1. 1.Downloaded Gcloud CLI tools and installed app-engine-java on it.
   2. Did a right click on the project in Eclipse (2023-12 / 4.30 version) and did Configure > Convert to Maven project
   3. Removed threadsafe in appengine-web.xml and added runtime as java11 and app-engine-apis property is set to true
   4. Updated the POM file to add the Google tools. Full POM is as below

.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SAAS_BWCS_GAE_J8</groupId>
<artifactId>SAAS_BWCS_GAE_J8</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version> <!-- or later-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After this, I did Maven / Update Project and ran the goals in Eclipse as Maven clean package. The package WAR file is built fine. However when I run it on local development server I get the following error

```
024-02-23 23:46:29.758:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@7e1a1da6{/,file:///C:/data/MY_APP/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\data\MY_APP\src\main\webapp}
```

MultiException[javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.myapp.MyServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet, javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.myapp.EmailServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet]

I thought it might be a local development server issue and deployed to cloud using

```
appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=my_app_id -Dapp.deploy.version=newj11 -Dapp.deploy.promote=True
```

However, on the live version on the google cloud, I get the same error too and the server won't start.

```
Failed startup of context c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext@6d2c0e53{/,file:///workspace/,UNAVAILABLE}{/workspace} MultiException[javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.myapp.MyServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
```

I thought it is because I included javax.servlet in dependency and removed it. If I remove it, the code does not compile in maven compile. I have been at this for more than 7 hours now and I am lost. Can anyone help on how to fix this and get this deployed. The change itself is very small one line change but Google is making it so difficult to migrate / deploy

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this document [Cloud Tools for Eclipse release notes](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/release-notes)

> Note: Cloud Tools for Eclipse is only compatible with the App Engine Java 8 runtime, which will reach the end of support on January 31, 2024.

As per this [Github Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3710#issuecomment-1477001825), at the moment Java 11/17 support for the App Engine standard on Cloud Tools for Eclipse is not available.

There is an open github thread [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2665), you can add your concern to the same issue.Also feel free to raise a [Public issue tracker](http://www.issuetracker.google.com/) or [Feature request](http://www.issuetracker.google.com/) describing your concern. You can use [this page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) for reference when creating an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the github links. It is disappointing that Google is choosing not to support Eclipse plugin. However, I am looking for how to deploy successfully using gcloud / maven appengine::deploy that is failing.

Comment: check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-maven#changing_the_deployment_defaults) & this [thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-plugins/issues/992)